# How to use toHaveBeenCalledWith on an object assignement

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Until now I have been using the following construct quite a lot:

```
spyOn(ClassToSpy, NameOfMethodToSpy);
```

...
expect(ClassToSpy.NameOfMethodToSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ObjectToCompare);

But now I would like to check the call to an exported object and not an exported function. Is this also possible with karma/jasmin?

To be more specific:
I have a service which gives me a reference to the global native browser window object:

```
 get nativeWindow(): any {
    return window;
  }
```

My code under test does the following with this returned window object:

```
this.winRef.nativeWindow.location.href  = clean_uri;
```

Now I want do be sure that this href property of the location has received the new url. As there was no function involved in this last call I can not use the toHaveBeenCalledWith-construct from karma/jasmine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly the answer to your question if it is possible to spy on plain exported objects. I guess it is not possible. But you have mentioned that you already have a service in place which wrapps the access to the window object. Therefore I would suggest that you add some getter / setter methods to this service in order to access the object. This way you can use the well known behaviour of spyOn(...) for functions.